# Cannot send even the simplest HTML Email in C# -

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I'm struggling, to get HTML Emails to work.
I started blaming gmail smtp, since I was using that, while developing, but have now posted code to my webhost, and I still can only send plain text.
I'm really sure that it's a really stupid small thing that I'm missing, but I can't cut away more code. I can't make it simpler, and it's still showing up as plain text in my outlook.

Here's my source:

```
  var EmailMessage = new MailMessage();
  EmailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
  EmailMessage.Body = @"test...<br><b>Bold text</b>";

  using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.123.com")) {
    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    smtpClient.Send("no-reply@123.com", "test@123.com", "Account verification", EmailMessage.Body);
  }
```

This results in a plain text email with this content: 
test...<br><b>Bold text</b>

**EDIT:**
Changed

```
  var EmailMessage = new MailMessage();
  EmailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
  EmailMessage.Body = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=""utf-8"" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
Test<br/>
<b>Bold text</b>
</body>
</html>";

  using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.123.com")) {
    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    smtpClient.Send("no-reply@123.com", "test@123.com", "Account verification", 
         EmailMessage.Body);
  }
```

Still ends up as plain text :(

Comment: Your body string is not valid html.  HTML need proper tags and does not start with "test..."

Comment: I have tried 
<html>test...<br><b>Bold text</b></html>

<html><body>test...<br><b>Bold text</b></body></html>

<html><head></head><body>test...<br><b>Bold text</b></body></html>

Comment: Still not valid.  From VS menu : Project : Add New Item : HTML Page.  Then paste your html and get the errors out before using.

Comment: Still the same, only plain text, with all html tags visible.

Comment: Are you getting exactly what you sent?  If so then it just how you are viewing the results.  HTML is text.  So you just need to put text into a viewer that can display html.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my intention. 
I want outlook or gmail to display the email as it's formatted by the HTML

Comment: Your original issue was sending.  Now it is a Formatting issue?  I just looked at one of my emails and it start with this : <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""><html dir="ltr"><head><META content="IE=10.000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">

Comment: My original issue was and is, sending an email with html, that actually show the formatting, so that I read a nice formatted email, and not seing the html tags in the email. 
I'm not sure I can explain it better.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up solving it, and it was a stupid small thing.
I sent the EmailMessage.Body instead of instead of Just EmailMessage

Here is my code now:

```
var EmailMessage = new MailMessage();
EmailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
EmailMessage.Body = @"test...<br><b>Bold text</b>";

using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.123.com")) {
    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    smtpClient.Send("no-reply@123.com", "test@123.com", "Account verification", 
         EmailMessage);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was doing the same thing! Haha what a ridiculous bug.